# Determining the coordinates of the BoundingBox of an object in an image

Tags: image-processing

I want to calculate and store the coordinates of the bounding box of the object area. I developed the following code, but it does not give the expected result. How can I fix it?

```
{{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}} = ComponentMeasurements[img, "BoundingBox"][[1, 2]];
ImageTake[img,{xmin,xmax},{ymin,ymax}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think this has to do with the fact that [images get flipped](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32377/29734).

Comment: Use `ImageTrim` instead of `ImageTake`. `ImageTrim` takes coordinates, while `ImageTake` takes indices.

Comment: `{{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}} == 1 /.   ComponentMeasurements[i, BoundingBox"];ImageTrim[i, t]`

Comment: a boolsheet software! A lot of bugs, I did not see what is the importance of indices and coordinates, It makes a lot of confusion! What is the clever thing behind! A very stupid programmation

Comment: @Developer2000 What are you talking about?  This is probably not the venue to vent undirected frustration with *Mathematica.*  There are undeniably frustrating aspects to the software but obviously many people find value in it anyway.  I hope you are reporting any bugs you find so that there is at least hope of them being fixed.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, There a lot of thing that does not make any sense. What the importance to implements two functions that do exactly the same thing! Nothing! What is the importance to get indices and coordinates. It makes a lot of confusion. ImageDimension[img] and Dimensions[ImageData] are inversed! Why? I think it is for nothing! I have never seen this confusion with Matlab, python or R...

Answer (score 4):

As detailed in the documentation:

> `ImageTake` takes the rows of an image to be numbered from top to
>   bottom, starting at 1.

and

> In 2D, `ImageTrim` assumes that points {x,y} are in the standard image
>   coordinate system, where x runs from 0 to image width and y runs from
>   0 to image height. The point {0,0} corresponds to the bottom-left
>   corner of the image.

So, in this case `ImageTrim` would be the easiest choice:

```
bbox = 1 /. ComponentMeasurements[img, "BoundingBox"];
ImageTrim[img, bbox]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest solution is ImageCrop:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJc1A.png"];
ImageCrop[img]
```

[image]

This removes the all-black borders around the component.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}} = ComponentMeasurements[img, "BoundingBox"][[1, 2]];

roi=ImageTake[img,{ImageDimensions[img][[2]]-ymax,ImageDimensions[img][[2]]-ymin},{xmin,xmax}];
```